# How to trace the code that written in a .fla file on the Actions panel with jsfl?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, jsfl

Is there a way to reach the code that is on Actions panel in a flash file with jsfl?

Thank you guys alot for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a `Frame` object you access the `actionScript` property. See [this link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/extend/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9024f3f-7a95CS5.html)

Example code taken from there, which adds `stop();` to the first frame of the first layer on the timeline

```
fl.getDocumentDOM().getTimeline().layers[0].frames[0].actionScript = 'stop();';
```

If you want to change the AS of a symbol, you should first get its timeline by [`symbolItem.timeline`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/extend/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9024f3f-7d40CS5.html)